# How to hide/show a component inside another component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have my application looking something like below..

```
import FirstComponent from "./components/firstComponent";
import NextComponent from "./components/nextComponent";
import MyProgressComponent from "./components/progressComponent";

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <MyProgressComponent />
            <Route path="/" exact component={FirstComponent} />
            <Route path="/nextComponent" component={NextComponent} />   
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
}
```

As we can see `'MyProgressComponent'` is visible when we navigate between 'http://localhost:3000/' and 'http://localhost:3000/nextComponent' because it is directly nested under Router component in App component. But I want `'MyProgressComponent'` to be visible only in  'http://localhost:3000/nextComponent' and hidden in 'http://localhost:3000/'. Any suggestion ?

I can do this by importing `'MyProgressComponent'` inside each `component` wherever required but I don't want to duplicate it in each `component`.

Comment: if you don't want to import it in every file, you just add a condition that makes MyProgressComponent not displaying when the path is /

Comment: and  you can do one thing that you can import `MyProgressComponent` inside the `NextComponent`

Answer (score 1):

You can render multiple components using the below syntax

```
<Route path="/nextComponent" render={() => 
 <>
  <MyProgressComponent />
  <NextComponent />
 </>
} 
/>
```

Comment: Nice I like this solution too

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Crocsx comment you can apply following check on your code.

```
<Router>
  <div>
    {this.props.location.pathname === "/nextComponent" ?  <MyProgressComponent />: null}
    <Route path="/" exact component={FirstComponent} />
    <Route path="/nextComponent" component={NextComponent} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use switch provided by router to achieve this.

Something like below should work for you.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/nextComponent" component={MyProgressComponent} />
</Switch>
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact component={FirstComponent} />
  <Route path="/nextComponent" component={NextComponent} /> 
</Switch>
```

more documentation is available here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components